# C# universal app: automatically scroll to bottom of textbox after setting new text programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

```
{
   var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(OutputTextBox.Text);
   stringBuilder.Append("sample text\n");
   OutputTextBox.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

How to automatically scroll to the bottom of the textbox after inserting a new text? I have read that it had worked with the .append method. Unfortunately this method does not exist within universal apps. The textbox is read-only.

The .xaml looks like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="175" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="337" RenderTransformOrigin="1.774,9.9" Margin="95,95,-370,-223">
            <TextBox x:Name="OutputTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="175" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="337" RenderTransformOrigin="1.774,9.9" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" IsReadOnly="True"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

What I have tried to do is:

```
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(OutputTextBox.Text);
            stringBuilder.Append("sample text\n");
            OutputTextBox.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
            ScrollViewer.ChangeView(0.0f, double.MaxValue, 1.0f);
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.aspx) has an embedded [ScrollViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx) by default. We can find it in [TextBox styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx). There is no need to put `TextBox` inside another `ScrollViewer` again.

> Scrolling using a scroll-wheel or touch is automatically enabled when needed. However, vertical scrollbars are not shown by default. You can show the vertical scrollbars by setting the [**ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) to **Auto** on the embedded [**ScrollViewer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx), as shown here.
>
> ```
> <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
>          MaxHeight="172" Width="300" Header="Description"
>          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
> ```

For more info, please see the **Enable multi-line input** section in the **Remarks** of [TextBox class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.aspx).

So to scroll to the bottom of a TextBox, we can get the embedded `ScrollViewer` first and then use [ChangeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.changeview.aspx) to scroll the text inside the TextBox. Following is a simple example:

```
private void ScrolltoBottom(TextBox textBox)
{
    var grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(textBox, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grid); i++)
    {
        object obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, i);
        if (!(obj is ScrollViewer)) continue;
        ((ScrollViewer)obj).ChangeView(0.0f, ((ScrollViewer)obj).ExtentHeight, 1.0f);
        break;
    }
}
```

However, here is an issue when using `ChangeView` method, we can not scroll back with scroll-wheel or touch after we use this method in `TextBox`. As a workaround, we can use [ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset.aspx) provisionally.

```
private void ScrolltoBottom(TextBox textBox)
{
    var grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(textBox, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grid); i++)
    {
        object obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, i);
        if (!(obj is ScrollViewer)) continue;
        //((ScrollViewer)obj).ChangeView(0.0f, ((ScrollViewer)obj).ExtentHeight, 1.0f);
        ((ScrollViewer)obj).ScrollToVerticalOffset(((ScrollViewer)obj).ExtentHeight);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change view on ScrollViewer like this after setting new text:

```
ScrollViewer.ChangeView(0.0f, double.MaxValue, 1.0f);
```

or use `ScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();`

And add to ScrollView this settings:

```
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AllowDrop="False" ManipulationMode="Control"
```

You have like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="175" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="337" RenderTransformOrigin="1.774,9.9" Margin="95,95,-370,-223" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AllowDrop="False" ManipulationMode="Control">
```

Comment: I have alread tried
            ScrollViewer.ChangeView(0.0f, double.MaxValue, 1.0f);
but it does not work and ScrollToEnd() does not exist unfortunately.

Comment: ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(); this is what I also tried. Aswell as some other possible solutions I have found on SO. Maybe I am just going to append the newest message to the beginning of the textbox.

Comment: @mollwitz But textbox text is update? I update what maybe you must do.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, don't get.